# A Maven dependency where newer JARs don't work with my JDKs

Tags: maven

1. Jackson is a JSON library.  The JARs released for v2.0-v2.7 work on JDK 6+.  v2.8 requires JDK 7+.
2. I have a library "Blah" that depends on any Jackson and works with any 2.x version.  Blah itself works on JDK 6+.

Here's the scenario I'm worried about: Someone uses "Blah" in their Android project.  If they're targeting JDK 7+, it's fine for Maven to transitively pull in Jackson v2.8.  But if the project needs to run on JDK 6, how can Maven know to pull in Jackson v2.7 instead?

One fix is for to add a `<dependencyManagement>` section to the Android project's "pom.xml".  Other than this being tedious, it's a painful process even figuring out that it's necessary.  People will first just do the normal dependency thing and run into weird "unsupported class file format" errors.  After that, they'll have to search around to figure out what the problem is and then add the `<dependencyManagement>` section (if they even know what it is).

Is there a way to make Maven behave correctly by default?  For example, is there a way for Jackson v2.8's "pom.xml" to say it requires JDK 7+ and the Android project's "pom.xml" say that it needs to run on JDK 6?  That should give Maven all the information it needs, right?

Comment: Behave "correctly" by default? "Correctly" depends on context, and Maven cannot guess context.

Comment: The sentence after the one you quoted describes the additional information I want to give to Maven.  Is that not enough context?

Comment: No, that describes your project, not your project's dependencies. Your project's dependencies describe themselves in *their* pom.

Comment: I described two pieces of additional information.  (1) Jackson v2.8's "pom.xml" says that it requires JDK 7+.  (2) The Android's "pom.xml" says that it must work on JDK 6.  That is enough information to know that the Android project won't work with Jackson v2.8.  Now how do I get Maven to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

With Maven3, use the "provided" scope and let the consumers of your libraries bring in the appropriate Jackson library for either JDK7/8/whatever, assuming the interfaces/APIs are the same it should just work.

Comment: One of the features of Maven is transitive dependency resolution.  I'm looking for a solution that lets users of Blah rely on that feature instead of figuring out the transitive dependencies themselves.

Comment: It's the transitive dependencies that are causing the problem.  While it's possible to have different profiles to bring in the Jackson dependency based on JDK, once it's build there's a comprehensive POM file that defines explicitly which Jackson library to use.  There's nothing that allows runtime-dependency changes like you're thinking of, you put in Blah in someone else's dependencies it's going to bring in whatever was used for compiling.  By using provided scope, you compile with whatever version you want but turns off the transitive dependency so the consumer can provide what is appropos

Comment: Let's say Blah specifies a Jackson dependency with the version range "[2.0,2.7)".  When you compile Blah to a JAR, Maven will pick some version of Jackson that satisfies the range.  But when you upload to Maven Central, the uploaded POM still includes the Jackson dependency as the version range "[2.0,2.7)", at least that's what I'm seeing on Maven Central.

What is this "comprehensive POM file" you're talking about?  Maybe I'm missing a build step?

Comment: First warning is that Maven version ranges can be tricky, especially M3 where they rewrote it all.  Regardless, if Jackson is v2.8+, that should be the version Maven pulls.  Maven resolves/pulls dependencies before compilation, so even if your consumer if JDK6 Maven is going to pull v2.8+ because that's the latest in the range and you've failed.  There's no way to end the range at 2.7 for JDK6 while leaving it open-ended for JDK7+, maven's not that smart.